# sequence and series (complex analysis) part 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

If a sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}$ has the following properties:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\alpha>1,$$ then 
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \right|^{1/n}\geq \alpha.$$

I found this statement on a paper but I cannot prove it. Could you please help me or give me an idea? Thank you so much for your help.

Masik

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \alpha$, the power series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $\frac{1}{\alpha}$. So the power series

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k x^n,$$

which is the Cauchy product of the power series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty x^n$ (which has radius of convergence $1$) and $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n$, has radius of convergence $R$ greater than or equal to $\min\{1, \frac{1}{\alpha}\} = \frac{1}{\alpha}$. Thus

$$\alpha \le \frac{1}{R} = \limsup_{n\to \infty} \left|\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k\right|^{1/n}.$$

Comment: Thank you for a very nice proof.

Answer (score 0):

a_n >=abs(a^na_1-1)/abs(aa_1-1)>=absa^n(a-1)/abs(denominator). If you raise to the nth root the denominator goes to 1 and the numerator goes to a.